# Fourier Transform of an asymmetric function

Tags: fourier-transform

For a normal $ \frac 1 { x ^ 2 } $ function, the Fourier Transform is simply the delta Function, with a constant in front. It took me a while to understand the reason for this and the power of derivatives.

I can ask the question two ways:

1. Is it possible to *split* the Fourier Transform in half, the negative side and the positive side and how would I do this?
2. Let us make the inverse square function asymmetric, the following way, where $ a \ne b $:
   $$ f ( x ) = \begin {cases}
   \frac 1 { a x ^ 2 } & x < 0 \\
   \frac 1 { b x ^ 2 } & x > 0
   \end {cases} $$
   I would like to take the Fourier Transform of this second function.

For me right now, this is an intellectual exercise.
For you background, I have degrees in Physics, Mathematics, and Computer Science.  It has been a LONG time since I had to do a Fourier Transform.  After reading many web sites, many times, I have an understanding of the Fourier Transform of $ \frac 1 { x ^ 2 } $; but not if it is asymmetric.

Comment: It's not clear. Can you describe more

Comment: You have to specify how you define the distribution $f_{\mathcal D}$, that is, how $(f_{\mathcal D}, \phi)$ is computed. If you only require $f_{\mathcal D}$ to be a regularization of $f$, there are many such $f_{\mathcal D}$. For any choice of a regularization of $1/x^2$, the FT is not equal to $C \delta^{(n)}(k)$. There is a standard way to define $x_+^{-n}$ which is a regularization of $H(x)/x^n$, but one has to keep in mind that $dx_+^{-n}/dx \neq -n x_+^{-n - 1}$ (for that regularization) and $(a x)_+^{-n} \neq a^{-n} x_+^{-n}$ (for any regularization).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'regularization of f'.

Comment: Looking at several web sites (Wolfram|Alpha, Wikipedia, Mathworks) the FT of 1/x^2 is  Cδ(n)(k), and I understand how to do that.
It has occurred to me that if I break up the function using H(x), for a left and right then I can do a FT on both sides.  Currently it is not clear to me how to do  H(x)/x^2. This link has the result of right side exponential function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.fourier.html
I now need to figure out how they got the result.